# How can i add stylized cracks on my sculpture?

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

How can i add cracks on my stylized game asset sculpture ? And how to get a good result without having to increase the polycount? Also how can i get a non-destructive workflow where i can continue to sculpt without the cracks and then edit the cracks?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Most artists are dragging an alpha of a stylized crack on their sculpture, you can find a set of popular alpha on the Gumroad page of Michael Vicente aka Orb here: https://gumroad.com/l/nOkHw
You will also need an high polycount to apply the alpha's details.

But the best way to apply cracks is by creating a mesh that you will use to cut your mesh with boolean, you will get more realistic cuts and non-destructive (with Modifiers and BoolTool brushes). You can use the BoolTool to work faster, you will have to select your crack mesh (completely closed) first then the mesh to cut and use the Difference operation.

[image]

If you use the Brush Boolean menu in the booltool you will be able to edit the cracks. Add an edge split modifier with a 30 degree angle to display your cracks correctly, sometimes the smoothing appears badly arround booleans.

[image]

Comment: I think you should post screenshot from Blender window, not from ZBrush. As you don't mention that, this might cause some misunderstanding.

Comment: "sometimes the smoothing appears badly arround booleans" - 30° edge split won't save you, there will be always a bad smoothing after boolean on low or mid poly curved areas on mesh. That takes a lot of work to clean up. Booleans on high-poly in Blender are very slow and not feasible. That's the reason to prefer those alphas or to do booleans in ZBrush or other apps. I also don't see why those slash marks are called "incorrect cracs" - there is nothing incorrect about them.

Comment: Booleans are fast because we don't need to get millions of polygons to project the cracks details, you can even project a clean crack on a face with no subdivision. But Blender is slow in high poly and the drag stencil is very laggy and work well only on flat surfaces, using boolean is the only option for Blender users. Also with Boolean cracks applied as modifiers or BoolTool Brushes it is possible to edit them and have a non-destructive workflow.

Comment: On low-poly booleans are fast, but they also destroy shading. You are misleading by only showing perfect examples on flat surfaces - booleans have to be cleaned if you want quality. If you add non-destructive into the equation and you want fast quality low-poly booleans you have only one option and that is to use Houdini.